# How to detect Daylight saving of EST timing?

Tags: .net, vb.net, timezone

I have developed a clock which shows `IST` & `EST` timings. I am from India, so my system clock setting uses `IST` settings. I want to display `EST` daylight timings in the clock. How can I display daylight saving timing of `EST`?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [FindSystemTimeZoneById](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.findsystemtimezonebyid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method like this:

```
    Dim istNow = System.TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(Now, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time"))
    Dim estNow = System.TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(Now, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time"))
    Debug.WriteLine(istNow.ToString)
    Debug.WriteLine(estNow.ToString)
```